# Merge column header in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've been try to merge the header column from 2 into 1, but the example and i already tried it with something like this 
`GridView.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, oGridViewRow);` the question and the example that floating around was just adding 1 column, and add it in the top of the old column, not merging it. So i want to actually merging 1 column and the rest of the column is still the same. Here is the picture of gridview column that i want to merge :

[image: GridView]

I want to Merge the "Action" column header from 2 into 1. So below the action column, there will be an edit and delete.

Oh i almost forgot, Here is the gridview code that handle the action column :

```
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" HeaderText="Action"/>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="linkDelete" runat="server"
                    CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("XXX")%>'
                    OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you want to delete?')"
                    Text = "Delete" OnClick = "DeleteDetail"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I am strictly against hard-coding, this is what I have, you can write this in 'RowDataBound' event of gridview:-

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
      e.Row.Cells[3].ColumnSpan = 2;
      e.Row.Cells[4].Visible = false;
      e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "Action";
}
```

Here, You need the change the cell index according to your gridview design.

Comment: Yeah thanks dude, finally it works. I just have to change the index and make the column that i want to turn into invisible.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Templates to customize how your column header and data look like
The below is a very simplified example that should show the desired result
But you will need to work on hadnling Edit and Delete actions your own way

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">            
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <div> Action </div>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <a href="#">Edit</a> | <a href="#">Delete</a>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

As you see, my idea is not merging the headers of both columns. Rather, I put the data of of both columns in a single column under single header. I think it achieves the same result.

Comment: Yeah bro, i already handle the edit and delete action, But not using the a href, instead i'm using linkButton and showEditButton that already provided. check the question again to see the code, i already edit it. And for the href one, i dont want to use it because its so vulnerable. Thanks anyway

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean using href in specific, that's why I said "very simplified example". I was just providing the idea of templates as a solution. So, you can replace them with LinkButtons for sure. @Rahul-Singh's solution is good but as he mentioned it is hard-coded, you need to update indexes each time number of columns change

Comment: Yeah thats right that it is not good for hard-coding, especially if the column are changed dynamically, And your approaches is only using under 1 column and simple if i use it from the start.